# Validación de campos no obligatorios (opcionales)

Tags: laravel

Estoy validando unos campos y funciona bien, exceptuando dos campo que no son oblicatorios, me pide que cumpla las reglas si están vacíos en el formulario.

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required|date',
            'phone' => 'numeric|min:10',
            'address' => 'string|max:255'
]);
```

Los campos `phone` y `address` son opcionales pero me pide que sea tipo `string` o `numeric`, también la longitud en caso que los deje vacío en el momento de envíar el formulario.

Intenté agregando a la validación algo que ví en internet, `sometimes` y no funcionó, con `nullable` + las reglas no valida las reglas al completar los opcionales.

```
'phone' => 'nullable|numeric|min:10',
'address' => 'nullable|string|max:255'
```

y `somtimes`

```
'phone' => 'sometimes|numeric|min:10',
'address' => 'sometimes|string|max:255'
```

Utilizo laravel 7

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando Laravel, te recomiendo utilizar [Validator::make()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#manually-creating-validators), ya que te da más flexibilidad al momento de manejar los errores, puedes usar redirecciones.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
    'phone' => 'nullable|numeric|min:10',                                           
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
        // return $validator->messages();
        return redirect('alguna-ruta')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
}
```

Podrás notar que las reglas posteriores a `nullable` sí son tomadas. Es decir que si el valor de `phone` es distinto a nullable, entonces se validará que sea numérico y además ser mínimo 10.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder... Pero no, si completo el campo phone y le coloco tres digitos lo procesa, no muestra el error

Comment: Estás probando con postman?

Comment: No, directamente completando el formulario en el proyecto

Comment: Entonces algo estás haciendo mal, no debería pasarte eso.